# I could review more than 20 posts, even though there were less than 150 posts in the queue?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues

I searched over Meta SO and found that a user can review 20 Triage posts a day if there are less than 150 posts in that queue. And 40 Triage posts if there are more than 150 post in the Triage queue. But sometime I face difficulties. Today I reviewed 20 Triage posts and after that SO asked me

> Thank you for reviewing 20 triage questions; come back in 12 hours to
>   continue reviewing.

After some time I visited the [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) page for the First Post queue. There were 111 Triage posts. Stack Overflow allowed me to review more even though I had already reviewed 20 triage posts and there were not more than 150 posts.

When I reached 36 posts it again said

> Thank you for reviewing 20 triage questions; come back in 12 hours to
>   continue reviewing.

check the images below.
[image]

**And** this is the review image:

[image]

I expected it should now interrupt me at 40. Why was it interrupted at 36? I'm confused about reviewing. Can anyone please explain a little bit.

Why did Stack Overflow allow me to review more than 20 when there were 111 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The limit is dynamic, and the numbers on the `\review` page are heavily cached. Even if it says there are only 111 posts in the Triage queue, there are likely more or less.

If you're reviewing and hit your 20, then you're shown the message provided the queue is currently under 150 review items. If the queue increases in size, you can come back and do more reviews. If the queue hits below 150 items again, then you are back to being limited to 20 reviews.

The message makes sense at this point. You've done 20 reviews, the queue has dropped back to a limit of 20, and you are thanked for hitting your limit of 20 reviews. If you've done more than 20, then great! You were there to take advantage of a larger queue, but you've still hit the limit of 20 when the queue limit drops. If you come back, do 4 more reviews, and hit your limit of 40 before the queue drops back to a limit of 20, you'll see the message thanking you for doing 40 reviews.

Comment: But why is there a limit on the reviews in the first place?

Comment: There is a limit to prevent burnout. The limit increases from necessity, to try to get the queues lower. The thought is that the longer you review, the more tired of it you get, and the less carefully you review. There are other meta posts on the subject.

Comment: @Kendra I thought it was to prevent robo-reviewers from getting the Steward badge too quickly.

Comment: @DonaldDuck From what I've read, it's mostly for burnout prevention. The more you review with no break, the theory is, the worse you'll start to review.