# Review message says I reviewed 20, but history says I reviewed 40

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

Today I reviewed 40 Suggested Edits.  However, when I go back to the queue, the message that tells me I'm out of reviews says I've reviewed 20.

> Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today; come back in 5 hours to continue reviewing.

When I click on the Recent Reviews link, it says I've reviewed 40.  Why are the numbers different?  How did I review 40 if the limit is 20?

Comment: @Kendra - While I don't understand what the `limit` means and how the system allowed me to do more than my allowed limit!! But, it makes sense to re-word `Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today`, if you think you know it is valid.

Comment: Similar post on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173953/thank-you-for-reviewing-20-first-posts-today-but-i-reviewed-40

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The message is correct, though it is a little confusing if you don't understand the situation.

You see, the limit for the review queues is dynamic and depends on how large the queue is at a given moment in time. If the queue *currently* has 150 review tasks or more, the reviewers have a limit of 40 reviews a day. If the queue *currently* has less than that, then the limit is 20.

As we can see from the orange bubble in [your image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62ppo.png), which at your rep level should be only considering the edit queue I believe, there are 75 review tasks in the queue. That puts the limit at 20 reviews.

When you reviewed earlier, the limit was 40, and you hit that. Great! At that time, so long as your last review did not drop the queue under 150, the message would have read "40" and not "20".

The message knows that you hit your limit. At the moment you had hit the queue, the limit was 20 reviews. Therefore, the message was

> Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today

Which can be read as

> Thank you for hitting the review limit today

If you wait until the queue is up and the limit is again 40, you will see the message

> Thank you for reviewing 40 suggested edits today

And it won't be as confusing.

In summary, the queue thanks you for hitting the *current* review limit, not for how many reviews you have done. For another example of how this can be confusing, see [I could review more than 20 posts, even though there were less than 150 posts in the queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332281/)

Comment: Instead of creating this confusion for everyone, I believe in changing that line to `Thank you for hitting the review limit today` instead of just assuming people to read it as :)

Comment: That could work. If you feel strongly about the change, I suggest making a feature-request post. Make sure to explain why you think the change is important, how you think it will help, and perhaps provide a link back here to help show what you mean. You might also be able to use the other question I linked, and any more you can find through a search, to help show how the message can confuse users.

Answer (score 0):

The message only says

> Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today

It does not say

> Thank you for reviewing exactly 20 suggested edits today

You say you reviewed 40 edits. This means you first reviewed 20 edits, and then some more. So the message is not not incorrect, maybe a bit misleading.

You propose renaming it to

> Thank you for hitting the review limit today

However, I think that could be even more confusing. People will probably assume that the review limit is constant, but it is not. Then they will come to meta, asking why they are able to review if they hit the limit previously on the same day.

But maybe adding *at least* would remove some confusion

> Thank you for reviewing at least 20 suggested edits today

Comment: I'm not exactly specific about wording but your wording looks better than mine but may not avoid confusion altogether.  May be we can put this information in Q&A and add the link with the message so if someone has a doubt, they may try to refer the link and come to meta if it doesn't resolve.