# Thank you for reviewing 20 low quality posts today; come back in 2 hours to continue reviewing. after reviewing 35 posts

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I thought the limit is extended from 20 to 40 if the queue has ~150 reviews waiting. It turns out that the limit is actually dynamic and if the queue gets better the limit drops back to 20.

I reviewed 35 LQP and I got the following message:

> Thank you for reviewing 20 low quality posts today; come back in 2 hours to continue reviewing.

Obviously the number is misleading, because I reviewed more than 20. This raises questions for me.

1. If the number of pending reviews reaches 150 again today, can I finish my remaining 5 reviews?
2. Should the message say 20 when in fact I reviewed 35 posts?
3. Why is it not hard 20 or 40?

Comment: I would think that if it's possible to have a variable field in the message for the "come back in 2 hours" part, then it shouldn't be especially tricky to make the "Thank you for reviewing XX" part variable, too.

Comment: But the system already 'knows' how many reviews you've done today, as you can see in the "Stats" tab - this will correctly display 35 if you go there *immediately after* you see that Thank-you message.

Comment: It's not strictly incorrect: when you've done 35 reviews you *have* done 20 reviews. See also [Review message says I reviewed 20, but history says I reviewed 40](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335064/1364007).

Comment: @WaiHaLee Hehe! When I first saw such a message, I just assumed it was one of those *exquisitly rare* bugs (sorry, features) in the S.E. UI.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Which is why I never said it is wrong. I suggested that maybe it should give a real number or be pegged to 20 or 40 reviews.

Comment: But it ***is*** 'pegged' to 20 or 40. (The message, that is, not the limit.)

Comment: I answered my first question myself. I pushed another 30 answers into the queue and then I was able to finish my remaining 5 reviews. Now it says "Thank you for reviewing 40 low quality posts"

Comment: Also note that, even if you have done 40 reviews (and get *correctly* thanked for your efforts), if the queue size then later falls below the relevant threshold, the message shown in the 'all queues' list - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review) - will revert to the "20" version.

Answer (score 3):

1. yes, you can resume reviewing if the queue size would allow you to do 40 reviews instead of 20.
2. yes, it would seem it displays the current queue size rather than the number of reviews you've done. What it does it looks right most of the time though. You could report that as a bug if there's not a question already that mentions it.
3. because if the queue is small we'd rather you let others have a go too. We don't want to burn you out if we can help it. When it's large, all hands to the pump.