# "Low quality posts" counter overflows

Tags: bug, review-queues

During the review of "Low quality posts", I've noticed that the counter overflows (22/20).

[image]

After a simple refresh of the page, the counter was updated to (22/40)

[image]

Why the quota of possible reviews changed during my session from 20 to 40?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Review message says I reviewed 20, but history says I reviewed 40](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335064/review-message-says-i-reviewed-20-but-history-says-i-reviewed-40): *"the limit for the review queues is dynamic and depends on how large the queue is at a given moment in time"*

Comment: @Nick Yes it does. However, perhaps the counter should be updated too?

Comment: Indeed perhaps, I guess it was overlooked when developing the review queues as a one page app

Comment: @Syscall "*perhaps the counter should be updated too?*" unfixable - the amount of low quality posts is countless. :P